# What are the pros/cons of using the Gradle integration vs Spring Boot integration for Flyway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

Flyway has [several](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/) integration options.

I'm trying to determine what the pros/cons are of using the Gradle integration vs the Spring Boot integration given that your project is already using both Spring Boot and Gradle.

The only thing I can think of is that if you want to be able to do migrations without starting the application or want to save time by not migrating every time you start the app then the Gradle choice could be better.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as build time vs run time.

In general you will build an artifact once and deploy it to many environments, so run time is a much better fit.

However sometimes build time makes sense. This is primarily for situations where you need a fully migrated database as part of the build, in order to for example generate code based on the structure of that database using frameworks like jOOQ or QueryDSL.